# Typescript: Static method return value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have such class:

```
export class GlobalValidation {
    static emailPattern(control: AbstractControl): ValidationResult {
        var EMAIL_REGEXP = Pattern.EMAIL;
        return this.checkPattern(control, EMAIL_REGEXP);
    }

    static urlPattern(control: AbstractControl): ValidationResult {
        var URL_REGEXP = Pattern.URL;
        return this.checkPattern(control, URL_REGEXP);
    }

    static checkPattern(control: AbstractControl, pattern: any) {
        if (control.value != "" && !pattern.test(control.value)) {
            return {"incorrectPatternFormat": true};
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'checkPattern' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'checkPattern' of undefined
>       at GlobalValidation.urlPattern

What am I doing wrong?

When I rewrite class to this:

```
export class GlobalValidation {

    static emailPattern(control: AbstractControl): ValidationResult {

        var EMAIL_REGEXP = Pattern.EMAIL;

        if (control.value != "" && !URL_REGEXP.test(control.value)) {
            return {"incorrectPatternFormat": true};
        }

        return null;
    }


    static urlPattern(control: AbstractControl): ValidationResult {

        var URL_REGEXP = Pattern.URL;

        if (control.value != "" && !URL_REGEXP.test(control.value)) {
            return {"incorrectPatternFormat": true};
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Everything is fine.

Seems that something is obvious, but I miss it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `checkPattern` using `this`, albeit it being a static method. Call `checkPattern` using `GlobalValidation.checkPattern(...)`

Answer (score 2):

You can't access `this` from static method. Using static classes has one purpose and that is - you don't need to create a new instance of the class to use the method.

You should use `GlobalValidation.checkPatter(...)` as Phil Cap suggested or just rewrite it, so it doesn't use the properties of GlobalValidation class.